# signtypedata TRON network

Tags: digital-signature, tron

did somone here know how to create an offchain signature that can be validate like this onchain:

```
 address signatory = ecrecover(keccak256(abi.encodePacked("\x19\x01", domainSeparator, structHash)), v,r,s);
        const signMessage = await wallet._signTypedData(domain, types, value);
```

all the paramters wiil be recived in the smart contract function

it works in EVM but not in TRON.

i tried following docs tip712 but i don't understand what atomic type token is,some one can help me thank you